Register heater stopped working
My friend's in-wall register heater stopped working after someone stacked some things in front of it. I opened it up and it looks like there is no reset button on the safety shutoff (it's an older model). Any ideas how to reset it?


it overheated ...

If  by "safety shutoff" you mean that the object held by the two Phillips-head screws is a thermal fuse that has blown, then you'd need to replace that part.

N.B. Before performing any work on this, shut the breaker or remove the mains fuse to the heater. If at all unsure, shut the main breaker.

Ideally, find the make and model number of the heater and buy a replacement thermal fuse. Similar replacement parts (assuming 10 A, 240 VAC, perhaps 120°C) cost between US$1 and US$5. If you cannot find that information, hopefully you can find that by examining the part:

Unscrew the two Phillips-head screws and remove the clip.
Slide back the insulation and examine the part to determine if it is a thermal fuse.
Check the continuity of the fuse -- if blown, it should be an open circuit.


Replace the thermal fuse. It might have a quick-connect or crimp connector on the right, in that image. The left side might need to be soldered.

Apply insulation -- and there are conflicting needs. The insulation must be thin enough to allow heat to seep in, melting the fuse to prevent fire, and thick enough to prevent electrical short-circuit, or arcing if there's a voltage surge.

Reattach the clip.

Turn on power.



Thank you! Do you know if it could be replaced with a resettable thermal safety shutoff (like the new ones seem to have)?

It definitely should not be replaced, because a thermal fuse is failure safe, but a thermal switch could get stuck on and result in a fire. However, you could certainly put a lower temperature thermal switch in series with the fuse, as is done in clothes dryers. The switch should open before the fuse blows, and close again when things cool down.

Brilliant, thank you!
